# jQuery Fancybox is not supporting links are in post method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox

I want to manage a sql db table in a same page and not to navigate to other pages.
I've this code in the head

```
<head>
        <title>All Magazine Data</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.0.47/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.0.47/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />     
        <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $(".various").fancybox({
                        maxWidth    : 800,
                        maxHeight   : 600,
                        fitToView   : false,
                        width       : '70%',
                        height      : '70%',
                        autoSize    : false,
                        closeClick  : false,
                        openEffect  : 'none',
                        closeEffect : 'none'

                    });
                });
        </script>
    </head>
```

and here is the code that is not working.

```
<a class="various fancybox.iframe" href="viewthumb.php?url=http://localhost/rupok/img/cover.png">View Cover</a>
```

when the image is not valid, The page loads in the iframe. But when I linked valid image in get parameter, It shows an  message

```
The Requested Content Can not be loaded
```

Comment: what happens when you navigate to `viewthumb.php?url=http://localhost/rupok/img/cover.png`?

Comment: It just writes a HTML Content embeding the image according to the URL

Comment: Here is the Code,

<?php
if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
 $url = $_GET['url'];
?>

<center>
 <a download href="<?php echo $url;?>">Download</a>
 </br>
 <img height="70%" src="<?php echo $url;?>"/>  
</center>

<?php
}
else{  
    echo "Error";
}
?>

Answer (score 0):

You are using v3, but options from v2 - these versions are not compatible. None of the options you are using exists in v3. Use "data-type" attribute for setting content type.

That message appears if "Content Can not be loaded". Check developer tools to see what status if of your page request.